# Creating a derived class as a subset of superclass

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have created (for purely eductional value, this is not production code, there are libraries out there, more efficient implementations exist) a templated matrix class.

I want to do 2D graphics, so I need a 2D vector. Because of homogenous coordinates this will have three items. Moreover, I want a new constructor, I want someone to have an x and y value and him to be able to construct a 2D point without having to understand what a templated Matrix is and why there are 3 elements in this vector. Therefore, I create a derived class, because that is the only way I know how to do that:

```
#include "matrix.hpp"

// 3 rows because of homogenous coordinate system.
class Point2D: public Matrix<3, 1>
{
    public:
        Point2D(float x, float y) : Matrix<3, 1>({x, y, 1}) {}
};
```

Note that the derived class is more of a subset of `Matrix<N,M>`, it does not add any functionality, instead it restricts the templated type to `Matrix<3, 1>`.

Now I want to operate on my newly created Point2D:

```
    Point2D a(-1, 1);
    Matrix<3, 3> translate = {(1, 0, 2,
                               0, 1, -2,
                               0, 0, 1);

    Point2D out = translate*a;
```

And this is not allowed:

```text
g++ -I2dgfx/inc/ -Imatrix/inc/ -Iinc/ -std=gnu++20 -DDEBUG -Og -ggdb -Wall -Wshadow=local -Werror -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -MMD -MP -c 2dgfx/test/point2d.cpp -o obj/test/2dgfx/point2d.cpp.o
2dgfx/test/point2d.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void PointMatrix2D_translation_Test::TestBody()’:
2dgfx/test/point2d.cpp:23:28: error: conversion from ‘Matrix<3, 1>’ to non-scalar type ‘Point2D’ requested
   23 |     Point2D out = translate*a;
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~^~
make: *** [2dgfx/rules.mk:34: obj/test/2dgfx/point2d.cpp.o] Error 1
```

Which I get, a `Matrix<3,1>` is not the same as a `Point2D`. Except I want those two to be exactly equal, I just need that new constructor to hide the fact that this object representing a point in 2D space secretly has 3 elements of which the last is a `1` because of math. So a solution is to modify the `Point2D` class:

```
#include "matrix.hpp"

// 3 rows because of homogenous coordinate system.
class Point2D: public Matrix<3, 1>
{
    public:
        Point2D(float x, float y) : Matrix<3, 1>({x, y, 1}) {}
        Point2D(const Matrix<3,1>& mat) : Matrix<3, 1>(mat) {}
};
```

Which works, but is this the best way? Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: If they are supposed to be exactly the same, just move the constructor into the `Matrix` class. If it doesn't make sense for some specializations, you can disable it with a `requires` clause or `std::enable_if`/SFINAE or make `Point2D` a function returning a suitable `Matrix<3,1>`.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you ask ten C++ developers "is <X> the best way, or is there a better way to achieve that" you will get at least eleven different answers, so this is mostly a matter of opinion.

Comment: @user17732522 Please do not put answers in the comments, what if I want to accept your comment as the answer? That is now impossible.

Comment: @Cheiron Sorry, I should have been clearer. My intention was not for the comment to be an answer. Rather I wanted to figure out whether you have a reason for making `Point2D` a separate type. That wasn't clear to me from the question.

Comment: `using Point2D = Matrix<3, 1>;`  If Point2D needs member methods of its own, consider putting them as methods in Matrix or as free standing functions.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use a derived class at all.   I'd simply use a `typedef Matrix<3,1> Point2D` or (C++11 and later) `using Point2D = Matrix<3,1>`.   That sorts out all of your requirements except that the last element of a `Point2D` is `1.0` instead of `0.0`.   There are a number of (relatively simple) options to address that, depending on which (minimum) C++ standard you are targeting - I'll leave working out those options as an exercise.

Comment: @Peter Please do not post answers as comments, that way I cannot accept them as answers. Also `Ill leave working out those options as an exercise` How exactly? Do I get a copy of every spec and enumerate the possible options? If I could figure out all possible options I would probably not have asked the question.

Comment: @user17732522 Ah, I clarified the question. I create a derived class because that is the only way I know to get what I want. Not because I want this derived class.

Comment: @Cheiron - I didn't provide an answer.   I stated a view on the nature of the question.  It wouldn't be difficult to modify the `Matrix` class to initialise members of the array to some initial value specified by users of the class (and even to default them).   There is some real-world expectation that, when you are designing or implementing software, you solve some problems for YOUR task at hand rather than demanding that others work out solutions (or relative merits of possible options) for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which works, but is this the best way? Is there a better way to achieve what
> I want?

The best way depends on how you intend to use your `Point2D`.

If you really want `Point2D` and `Matrix<3,1>` to be the same, a possible approach is to make `Point2D` a type alias and write a `make` function to create it:

```
using Point2D = Matrix<3, 1>;
Point2D make_point_2d(float x, float y) { return Point2D{x, y, 1}; }

int main() {
    auto const a = make_point_2d(-1, 1);
    Matrix<3, 3> translate = {1, 0, 2, 0, 1, -2, 0, 0, 1};

    Point2D out = translate * a;
}
```

To keep the design consistent, I'd introduce type aliases and `make_*` functions for other types too. E.g.:

```cpp
using Matrix3x3 = Matrix<3,3>;
Matrix3x3 make_matrix_3x3(/* ... */) { /*...*/ }
```

This may work as long as the type aliases you need to introduce are not too many.

---

**Edit:** I'm not really sure having `Point2D` be (or publicly inherit from)
`Matrix<3,1>` is a good idea. As a user, I'd be quite surprised by the fact
this code would compile (and run without causing any `assert` to fail):

```
auto const a = make_point_2d(-1, 1);
a(2,0);

// 1. Why do I need the second index to access the elements of a Point2D?
// 2. Why can I access the element at index 2?
```